# Ruby what does star prefix means in a loop variable?

Tags: ruby

I've ecountered this today and I have no idea what it means. I tried to google it but I had no luck. Can someone explain this to me?

```
combinations.each do |combination|
  messages = EventNotification.where('user_id = ? AND message_template = ?', *combination)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called the *splat operator*, and it unpacks an array into single method arguments. In this case, because the function presumably expects two more arguments after the format string, it's equivalent to:

```
messages = EventNotification.where('user_id = ? AND message_template = ?',
                                   combination[0], combination[1])
```

In other languages, this feature is often called "varargs".